# WCF service returning object in Json format

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, wcf

I have a WCF service and I am building an object called `FinalList` that contains an Object called Chart and a `List<Data>`.
I want to return to my ajax function json data in the format below:

> {"d":{"chart":{"caption":"Year","exportatclient":"1","exportenabled":"1","exporthandler":"chartExporter","labelDisplay":"wrap","numberprefix":"","showborder":"1","slantLabels":"1","useroundedges":null,"yaxisname":"Number
>   of
>   hits"},"data":[{"label":"1960s","link":null,"tooltext":null,"value":3},{"label":"1970s","link":null,"tooltext":null,"value":56},{"label":"1980s","link":null,"tooltext":null,"value":98}]}}

However my Service is returning like this:

> {"d":{"__type":"FinalList:#MyNamespace.FusionChartsFields","chart":{"__type":"Chart:#MyNamespace.FusionChartsFields","caption":"Year","exportatclient":"1","exportenabled":"1","exporthandler":"chartExporter","labelDisplay":"wrap","numberprefix":"","showborder":"1","slantLabels":"1","useroundedges":null,"yaxisname":"Number
>   of
>   hits"},"data":[{"__type":"Data:#MyNamespace.FusionChartsFields","label":"1960s","link":null,"tooltext":null,"value":3},{"__type":"Data:#MyNamespace.FusionChartsFields","label":"1970s","link":null,"tooltext":null,"value":56},{"__type":"Data:#MyNamespace.FusionChartsFields","label":"1980s","link":null,"tooltext":null,"value":98}]}}

When I used WebServices (asmx) I only needed to declare my class as "object" instead of FinalList, then the results were in the correct json format I need.

I have tried converting it into string and it brings me the correct thing but including '\' (e.g. {"d":{\"chart\":{\"caption\":\"Year\") and that's not what I want.

Does anyone know how I can remove these "__type" and class name?

I am using .Net 4

My FinalList class is as follows:

```
public class FinalList
    {
        private Chart _chart;
        private List<Data> _data = new List<Data>();

        public Chart chart
        {
            get { return _chart; }
            set { _chart = value; }
        }

        public List<Data> data
        {
            get { return _data; }
            set { _data = value; }
        }
    }
```

My service contract contains

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
```

above its declaration.

Comment: What does your model class definition look like? (`__type` is usually a hint to the DataContractSerializer about how to translate interfaces or abstract base classes.)

Comment: My class in my svc.cs has "[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]" above its declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the result is wrapped in an additional type (presumably to allow for multiple results?) and there's a __type property attached to each object returned. Even simple result values at least include the wrapper type, so even say a string result includes the d: type.

If you're using MS AJAX on the client there's no issue - the client knows how to parse this JSON into a clean object. But if you're using some other mechanism - jQuery or Prototype for example to retrieve a result set you get back a funky object where you have to go result.d.LastName for example, which is ugly.

Try this,

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
```

Comment: maybe but you wrote "Does anyone know how I can remove these "__type" and class name?"

Comment: So are you saying I can only change this if I change my ajax call? I cannot do anything from my WCF service?

Comment: Change the attribute in your service ! not jour js. Also it can be simpler to test in browser with a WebGet.

Comment: Sorry, I have already changed according to your example but nothing changed. But I am still using jQuery to make the ajax call.

Comment: what behavior are you using ? <enableWebScript /> or <webHttp/> ?

Comment: I was using <webHttp/> then I changed to<webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"/>

Answer (score 1):

What behaviour are you using for your WCF service? If you are using `<enableWebScript />` then switching to `<webHttp/>` in the service behaviour configuration will solve your problem.

As Cybermaxs said, if you are using an ASP.NET Ajax client then this won't be a problem and you may continue to use `<enableWebScript />`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a constructor as below:

```
public class FinalList
{
    private Chart _chart;
    private List<Data> _data = new List<Data>();

    public Chart chart
    {
        get { return _chart; }
        set { _chart = value; }
    }

    public List<Data> data
    {
        get { return _data; }
        set { _data = value; }
    }

    protected internal FinalList() { }

}
```